# sending content-type json instead of rendering page

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ejs

I have this code:

```
router.get('/findRecord', authCheck, (req, res) => {
  let amountOfTokens = req.session.amountOfTokens
  request.post({
    url: 'https://myurl.com/user_records',
    headers: {
      "Cookie": req.headers?.cookie,
    },
    json: {
      max_date: new Date().valueOf()
    }
  }, async function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    // console.log(body)
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        if (amountOfTokens == undefined || amountOfTokens == null) {
          res.redirect('/dashboard')
        }
        let numOfRecords = body.length
        res.render('dashboard.ejs', {data: req.data, body: body, amountOfTokens: amountOfTokens, numOfRecords: numOfRecords})
    }
})
})
```

what happens is, when I render doing this:

```
res.render('dashboard.ejs', {data: req.data, body: body, amountOfTokens: amountOfTokens, numOfRecords: numOfRecords})
```

on the front-end, it somehow returns `content-type: json header` and `json content`
and the browser isn't rendering the page, just the shows `JSON header` and the path to what the page that were supposed to be going to.

and `body`, which returns all the users records, looks like this:

```
[
  { 
    id: '912342930198368362323',
    user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    name: 'hello world',
    date: 1655400772,
    input: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    record_type: 'type1',
    output: 'hey',
    tokens: 43
  }
]
```

im not sure why this is happening. could someone share what they think could be the problem?

Answer (score -1):

use res.send() to display JSON instead of res.render()

more info here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-res-send-function/